# When and why to use hash tables in CL instead of a-lists?

Tags: data-structures, common-lisp, hashtable, sbcl

I use a-lists all the time.

When and why do you (or should you) use hash tables?

My reluctance to using them is that, unlike the other data structures, hashtables in CL are not visible lists. Which honestly, I find weird considering almost everything is a list.

Maybe I am missing something in my inexperience?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are lot of assumptions to address in your question:

> I believe common lisp is the only language I have worked with that have a variety of extremely useful data structures.

I don't think this is particularly true, the standard libraries of popular languages are filled with lot of data structures too (C++, Java, Rust, Python)

> When and why do you (or should you) use hash tables?

Data-structures come with costs in terms of memory and processor usage: a list must be searched linearly to find an element, whereas an hash-table has a constant lookup cost: for small lists however the linear search might be faster than the constant lookup. Moreover, there are other criteria like: do I want to access the data concurrently? a List can be manipulated in a purely functional way, making data-sharing across threads easier than with a hash-table (but hash-table can be associated with a mutex, etc.)

> My reluctance to using them is that, unlike the other data structures, hashtables in CL are not visible lists. Which honestly, I find weird considering almost everything is a list.

The source code of Lisp programs is made mostly of Lists and symbols, even if there is no such restriction. But at runtime, CL has a lot of different types that are not at all related to lists: bignums, floating points, rational numbers, complex numbers, vectors, arrays, packages, symbols, strings, classes and structures, hash-tables, readtables, functions, etc. You can model a lot of data at runtime by putting them in lists, which is something that works well for a lot of cases, but they are by far not the only types available.

Just to emphasize a little bit, when you write:

```
(vector 0 1 2)
```

This might look like a list in your code, but at runtime the value really is a different kind of object, a vector. Do not be confused by how things are expressed in code and how they are represented during code execution.

If you don't use it already, I suggest installing and using the Alexandria Lisp libray (see https://alexandria.common-lisp.dev/). There are useful functions to convert from and to hash-tables from alists or plists.

More generally, I think it is important to architecture your libraries and programs in a way that hide implementation details: you define a function `make-person` and accessors `person-age`, `person-name`, etc. as well as other user-facing functions. And the actual implementation can use hash tables, lists, etc. but this is not really a concern that should be exposed, because exposing that is a risk: you won't be able to easily change your mind later if you find out that the performance is bad or if you want to add a cache, use a database, etc.

I find however that CL is good at making nice interfaces that do not come with too much accidental complexity.

Comment: "Do not be confused by how things are expressed in code and how they are represented during code execution." -- a profound point. And lesson I will not forget.

Comment: @Vinn also take notice of: _"More generally, I think it is important to architecture your libraries and programs in a way that hide implementation details...."_ If you write code in a way that doesn't depend on explicit representations code can be easier to read and easier to maintain and modify over the life-cycle of a program.

Comment: @adabsurdum what do you mean by "depend on explicit representations code"?

Comment: @Vinn -- Explicit representations expose implementation details. Suppose you want to work with a bunch of tables of data, and you decide to represent those tables with plists. You write a bunch of functions to do things with your tables. If you design your functions to operate explicitly on plists, then you will have to rewrite all of them if you decide that alists or hash tables would be better. Most of your functions don't care how tables are represented, they only want to be able to get the data they need from a table.

Comment: Instead you could write a few functions that get the data by explicitly operating on plists. Other functions can use these fundamental functions without knowing how tables are implemented. If you need to change the table representation you only need to rewrite the few functions that all of the others use to access tables.

Comment: interesting. Very valuable because my app is written exactly as you described - for alists only. If I understand you correctly, the architecture you suggest is `1.` write a few alist specific functions that get data. and then `2.` all other functions that require data are not "getting" data. Instead they just call the "getter" functions and use the data. Is that accurate?

Answer (score 6):

The hash table is very useful when you have to access a large set of values through a key, since the complexity of this operation with a hash table is *O(1)*, while the complexity of the operation using an a-list is *O(n)*, where *n* is the length of the list.

So, I use it when I need to access multiple times a set of values which has more then few elements.

Answer (score 4):

> My reluctance to using them is that, unlike the other data structures, hashtables in CL are not visible lists.

They are definitely not lists, but indeed they are not visible either:

```
#<HASH-TABLE :TEST EQL :COUNT 1 {100F4BA883}>
```

this doesn't show what's inside the hash-table. During development it will require more steps to inspect what's inside (inspect, describe, alexandria:hash-table-alist, defining a non-portable `print-object` method…).

#### serapeum:dict

I like very much [serapeum:dict](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/data-structures.html#printing-a-hash-table-readably), coupled with `(serapeum:toggle-pretty-print-hash-table)` (also the [Cookbook](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/data-structures.html#printing-a-hash-table-readably)).

```lisp
CL-USER> (serapeum:dict :a 1 :b 2 :c 3)
;; => #<HASH-TABLE :TEST EQUAL :COUNT 3 {100F6012D3}>

CL-USER> (serapeum:toggle-pretty-print-hash-table)

;; print the above HT again:
CL-USER> **
(SERAPEUM:DICT
  :A 1
  :B 2
  :C 3
 )
```

Not only is it printed readably, but it allows to create the hash-table with initial elements at the same time (unlike `make-hash-table`) and you can read it back in. It's even easy to save such a structure on file.

Serapeum is a solid library.

Now, use hash-tables more easily.

Answer (score 2):

When to use a hash-table: You need to do fast (approximately "constant time") look-ups of data.

When to use an a-list: You have a need to dynamically shadow data you pass on to functions.

If neither of these obviously apply, you have to make a choice. And then, possibly, benchmark your choice. And then evaluate if rewriting it using the other choice would be better. In some experimentation that someone else did, well over a decade ago, the trade-off between an a-list and a hash-map in most Common Lisp implementation is somewhere in the region of 5 to 20 keys.

However, if you have a need to "shadow" bindings, for functions you call, an a-list does provide that "for free", and a hash-map does not. So if that is something that your code does a lot of, an a-list MAY be the better choice.

```
* (defun lookup (alist key) (assoc key alist))
LOOKUP
* (lookup '((key1 . value1) (key2 . value2)) 'key1)
(KEY1 . VALUE1)
* (lookup '((key1 . value1) (key2 . value2)) 'key2)
(KEY2 . VALUE2)
* (lookup '((key2 . value3) (key1 . value1) (key2 . value2)) 'key2)
(KEY2 . VALUE3)
```